# Access Database query on finding specific character in a sentence

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm looking to find specific characters a column that has addresses. So this has numbers, characters and spaces. Using "like" does not seem to work. I tried using "instr," but I can't get it right....Is it because it has spaces?

So for example: 
1234 Arlington Hwy

I want to pull up any address records that has "Hwy" in it. Help please!

Comment: `like` is very appropriate for this.  You should show your query and explain how it is not working.

Comment: SELECT 
*
FROM Daily_Upload
WHERE Daily_Upload.Field11 like '%PO Box 10%'
;
So this is what I have that works. But if I just do '%po%' it doesn't pull it up

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1 LIKE '*Hwy*'
```

The * operator acts as a wild-card, allowing anything to come before and after "Hwy" to return.

Comment: In MS-Access, `*` is the "any number of characters" wildcard, not `%`.